# How to get a bootstrap modal dialog box to fade away slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal dialog (#busyIndicator'), which basically says `Please Wait`.  Sometime the operation completes way too fast so the dialog is essentially an epilepsy inducing blur between `$("#busyIndicator").modal('show');` and `$('#busyIndicator').modal('hide');`.

Is there a nice way to hide the modal that introduces delay in the way it fades out?  I tried `$('#busyIndicator').fadeOut(2000).modal('hide');`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You could try adding bootstrap's `fade` class to the modal?

Comment: @Malk It's in there.  `<div id="busyIndicator" class="modal fade">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input desired closing duration and modal selector.

```js
var timer,
    closingTime = 3000,
    modal = $('#myModal');

modal
    .on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        if (timer) {
            timer = false;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            timer = true;
            modal.animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, closingTime - 150, function () {
                modal.modal("hide");
            })
        }
    })
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        modal.css({
            opacity: 1
        })
    })
```

```css
.center-me {
   min-height: 50vh;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="center-me">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would run your JS as a callback of `$.fadeOut()`, so that the JS in the callback waits for `$.fadeOut()` to finish first.

```
$('#busyIndicator').fadeOut(2000,function() {
  $(this).modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  The code goes directly to `$(this).modal('hide')` - the interval of 2000 ms is ignored.

Comment: @AngryHacker are you sure you don't have something else going on? The callback is standard behavior... it doesn't run until the fade out finishes http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqEMNJ

Comment: I think your approach doesn't work with bootstrap modals.  Here is an example I cooked up: https://jsfiddle.net/8yr96pey/

Comment: @AngryHacker thanks for the demo, I rarely use bootstrap. This seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/8yr96pey/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout method. This is the simplest and efficient way i found.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(your_modal).modal('hide');
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modals fade by default, they have transitions setup in their css. However if you want to change the fade speed, use this;

```
.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

It should make fading way too slow, but then you can adjust the speed, by increasing the transition time from 1s to something smaller, like 30s.

Comment: I really wanted to upvote this solution as the best, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.